# How to hide TidioChat sidebar for printable version?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, printing

**Context**

I have a website with food recipes with a printable view styled by a dedicated CSS.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/front/print-recipe.css" media="print">`

The *show-recipe* view also loads a [TidioChat](http://tidiochat.com/) support widget that loads for users support.

**Problem**

When a printable version is loaded, the page preview loads a printer-ready layout that includes the chat widget, which covers part of the contents of the page (the actual recipe instructions).

[image: Example]

**Tried Approaches**

- I've tried programatically disabling the widget with javascript, however this approach becomes very tricky and requires re-enabling it after the print preview. I believe this is sort of dirty, and in any case I could not make it work as desired.
- I've also tried adding a custom override style (`display:none`) to the class `.sidebar-content`. No luck, still being displayed. [Screenshot](https://snag.gy/nwV9v3.jpg)
- I've also contacted TidioChat support. Their answer was there is not much to do: *I've talked with a dev on our team and I'm afraid there's nothing we can currently do to help you with that; that's because the printable versions of pages are mostly determined by the browser you're using, and we have no control over that. I'm really sorry about that.* However, I believe there must be a way to override the default CSS and let it be hidden for *print* media.

**Extra Info**

- I've done these trials with Google Chrome and Firefox, both having similar behavior about the sidebar chat widget.

**Link to actual page**

Here an [example real link with the actual problem](https://recetas.fimedi.net/recetas/tomates-rellenos-con-ricotta-y-jamon-cocido/ver).

---

Thanks for any possible help/hints. I will update this question post as required with any missing info that is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sidebar-content` is within the Tidio `iframe` and as such you can't make any styling changes to it due to [same-origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) policies.

You can however hide the entire Tidio `iframe` by hiding the containing `<div id="tidio-chat">` by adding the following to your `print-recipe.css`:

```
#tidio-chat {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That was really easy, I don't know how I didn't realize that before. Thanks very much for pointing this out @epsilon42 !